# LibreOffice — Convert images to shapes

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

Can we convert `svg` or `png` files to shapes like we can in PowerPoint with LibreOffice Impress? I've looked for a solution, but haven't found anything.

Comment: I know a different Linux-friendly app for that: **Inkscape**. It can convert bitmaps to vectors and save them as SVG (or export them into one of the numerous export formats it supports).

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I solved it

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late, but converting to a "metafile" will ensure that visual clarity remains intact:

[image: Whatever]

Right click on the image, select "Convert", then choose "To Metafile". This will allow you to keep the image clear when exporting, converting to a different format, or presenting on *really* large displays.

Comment: How does it work? What does it do under the hood?

Comment: It converts an image, be it SVG, PNG, JPG, or whatever, to an internal format used by LibreOffice. The internal format is easier for the rendering engine to deal with when exporting and scaling, which makes it possible to have a clearer image when performing various tasks. I would often have to do this when prepping presentations for displays wider than 4 metres, otherwise images were pixellated and disappointing.